# Calculate the sum function of power series

Tags: integration, power-series

I have the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
and I tried to calculate its sum function like this:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\int\cdots\int\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}(dx)^n
$$
just by first taking nth derivative and then integrating n times. From what I've learnt, in the region of convergence of this power series (which is obviously $(-\infty, \infty)$), the following equation holds:
$$
\int\cdots\int\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}(dx)^n=\int\cdots\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}(dx)^n=\int\cdots\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}(dx)^n
$$
that is, you can change the order of taking derivative and summing, and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$ is just $e^x$, so integrate it n times should also be $e^x$. So the sum function (the way I see it) is just $e^x$.

But this is obviously wrong, since there is no way $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$, but I don't know where is the mistake.

Comment: I know the correct answer is coshx and the right way to calculate it, I just dunno where my answer is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different $n$'s here:

- the one from taking the $n$<sup>th</sup> derivative;
- the one from the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$.

Note that this last series is just a short way of writing$$1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots$$and that, if you differentiate this expression $n$ times you will *not* get $e^x$.

Comment: Yes I was about thinking the same thing. But you see that I actually differentiate each term in the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ different times. It's like $\frac{d}{dx}1+\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots=1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...=e^x$

Comment: Or wait a minute do you mean the n in n^th derivative is a constant that goes to infinty?

Comment: Yes, but that's not all that I am saying. And no that, in your previous comment, you computes the first derivative of the first term plus the second derivative of the second term and so on. Why should that be something meaningful?

Comment: Because I thought that n used in differentiation is the same n that relates to a certain term. now I know that's wrong. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

An idea using a little basic complex analysis:

Clearly the convergence radius of this series is infinity, and

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\implies f(ix)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{i^{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}=:\cos x$$

and the above is true in fact for any $\;x\in\Bbb C\;$ . Thus, we  get

$$f(ix)=\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2\implies f(x)=f((-i)ix)=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}2=:\cosh x$$

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the previous answer for the sake of those perhaps looking how to actually find what is the function in the series without complex analysis. Note that if
$$
f(x)
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
 = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + \ldots,
$$
which is just the listing of all even powers of
$$
e^x
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}
 = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \ldots
$$
The trick to make $f(x)$ from $e^x$ is to find a way to negate the odd terms, which is to multiply all of them by $-1 = (-1)^n$ for odd $n$. Conventiently, for even $n$, we have $(-1)^n=1$ so there will be no change to even terms:
$$
e^{-x}
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}
 = 1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} \pm \ldots
$$
Now, adding $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ doubles the even terms, and cancels the odd terms. To "undo" the doubling, we halve the result to get
$$
\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}
 = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + \ldots,
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
 = f(x),
$$
so $f(x) = \cosh x$.

Comment: That's a good explanation, thx

Comment: @babybobby you should consider to put this answer as the correct of your question. It's more complete that the one you choose as the correct answer and has the correct result